# Get the number of comments awaiting moderation

Tags: comments, moderation

Is there any 'official' way to get the number of comments, awaiting moderation? I've taken a look at [get_comments_status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_comment_status) - is it what I need or are there other methods?

Answer (score 3):

You need [`wp_count_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_comments).

```
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
$comments_count->moderated; // (int) comments in moderation
```